# Каретка при нажатии на текст, ссылку или картинку в новом браузере Windows10

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

Знакомый показал, что в новом браузере Windows 10 при нажатии на любой элемент появляется каретка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Естественно никакого **contenteditable** нет. Такая фигня на всех сайтах.

Как можно это исправить?

```
<div id="page">
 <div id="title">Тарифы</div>
 <div id="title">Текст для раздела "Тарифы"</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Каретка в браузере Microsoft Edge (a.k.a. Project Spartan) — это пользовательская опция, режим для навигации по странице с помощью клавиатуры. Его можно включить по умолчанию в настройках браузера, можно нажать F7 для переключения в этот режим на текущей вкладке.

Сайтам с этой кареткой **ничего делать не надо**. Это сродни борьбе с рамкой фокуса на активном элементе или с курсором мыши. Даже если вы чего-то добьётесь, то вы только помешаете пользователям работать с вашим сайтом, особенно пользователям с ограниченными возможностями.

Comment: мне как-то неприятно видеть, когда куда не кликнешь, появляется каретка. Это не поле, чтобы делать вид, что там можно писать.

Comment: @ModaL Ну так зайдите в опции и отключите.